# fuelUx scheduler : datepicker Issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker, scheduler, fuelux

*When date picker selects a new date it  reloads page and resets the value to default how can I disable this? 
 http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/javascript.html#scheduler*

Comment: I don't have this problem. Maybe change your browser?

Comment: I am using chrome its same for chrome and safari as i select another date my page reloads :(

Comment: Try to install another browser or reinstall what you already have. Maybe you have a side-effect of a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the use of datepicker within a form. The control uses `<button>` without `type=button` which will submit the form. [Known bug #610](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/610).

This has been fixed for Fuel UX 3.0.1. There is a WIP branch if you need the code before the release.